# Converting SMTP message from ASCII to Unicode in Python

Tags: python, smtp, gmail

I am having trouble getting this email to send, I am passing the correct variables in, however I cannot send it due to the `£` not being in ASCII. I am not sure how to go about encoding the message, or even if the message needs to be encoded at all.

```
Sub = ("Event Consent")
Msg = (
    "Hello,\n Your Scout, %s , %s has expressed his interest in this event:\n"
    "Event Name: %s\n"
    "Event Start Date: %s\n"
    "Event End Date: %s\n"
    "Event Start Time: %s\n"
    "Event End Time: %s\n"
    "Cost: %s\n"
    "If you wish your son to not attend this event, please log into the system and remove him." % (FName, SName, ListValues[0], ListValues[1], ListValues[2], ListValues[3], ListValues[4], ListValues[5]))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.PASSWORD)
message = "Subject: {} \n\n {}".format(Sub, Msg)
print(message)
server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email, message)
server.quit()
print("Success!")
```

An example message:

```
     Your Scout, Woogles , TheStout has expressed his interest in this event:
Event Name: Woogles Event
Event Start Date: 23/11/2018
Event End Date: 27/12/2019
Event Start Time: 17:13
Event End Time: 24:13
Cost: £400
If you wish your son to not attend this event, please log into the system and remove him.
```

Error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xa3' in position 247: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have already tried:

```
Msg.encode('utf-8')
```

However this did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Further Questions:
Why does python require this to be in Unicode? I thought SMTP was based on Unicode already?

Comment: SMTP is not unicode aware (by default).  You should use the MIME Message classes to properly format your message, and do the appropriate encodings. (eg, the email module)

Comment: you also need to add the full traceback ...

Comment: @Max What do you mean by this? Why is it not possible to encode `Msg` into Unicode?

Comment: You will need to use Content-Transfer-Encoding and declare a character set and encode to an SMTP safe set.  You can do this yourself, but there is already a package in python to do this for you email.message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The smtplib.server.sendmail function in python raises UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853197/the-smtplib-server-sendmail-function-in-python-raises-unicodeencodeerror-ascii)