# The smtplib.server.sendmail function in python raises UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, character-encoding, smtplib

I am trying to edit a text file then send it as email body using a python script but im getting the unicode encoding error. After some research i found the solution as using the method .encode('utf-8') but this doesn't serve me as the sendmail() method only sends strings

Here is the python code snippet Im using:

```
irtem = open('irtemplate.txt')
data = irtem.read().replace('(name)', eng_name).replace('(customer)', 
cu_name).replace('(sr)', SR_num).replace('(problem)', 
prob_description).replace('(email)', eng_email).replace('(details)', 
details_req).replace('(tele)', eng_tele)


message_text = data
message = "From: %s\r\n" % fromaddr + "To: %s\r\n" % toaddr + "CC: 
%s\r\n" % ",".join(cc) + "Subject: %s\r\n" % message_subject + "\r\n" + 
message_text
toaddrs = [toaddr] + cc + bcc
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, message)
server.quit()
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "autoIR.py", line 39, in <module>
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, message)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/smtplib.py", line 855, in sendmail
msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in 
position 168: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`smtplib.server`'s [sendmail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail) method expects a `bytes` instance; if it gets a `str` it tries to encode it to ASCII, resulting in a `UnicodeEncodeError` if the `str` contains any non-ASCII characters.

You can workaround this by encoding the message yourself:

```
>>> msg = 'Hello Wørld'
>>> from_ = 'a@example.com'
>>> to_ = 'b@example.com'
>>> subject = 'Hello'

>>> fmt = 'From: {}\r\nTo: {}\r\nSubject: {}\r\n\r\n{}'

>>> server.sendmail(to_, from_, fmt.format(to_, from_, subject, msg).encode('utf-8'))
{}
```

This will send this message*:

```
b'From: b@example.com'
b'To: a@example.com'
b'Subject: Hello'
b'Hello W\xc3\xb8rld'
```

However this workaround will not work if you want to send non-text binary data with your message.

A better solution is to use the [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) class from the email package.

```
>>> from email.message import EmailMessage
>>> em = EmailMessage()
>>> em.set_content(msg)
>>> em['To'] = to_
>>> em['From'] = from_
>>> em['Subject'] = subject

>>> # NB call the server's *send_message* method
>>> server.send_message(em)
{}
```

This sends this message; note the extra headers telling the recipient the encoding used:

```
b'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"'
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'To: to@example.com'
b'From: from@example.com'
b'Subject: Hello'
b'X-Peer: ::1'
b''
b'Hello W\xc3\xb8rld'
```

---

* Run the command `python -m aiosmtpd -n -l localhost:1025`†  (Pre-Python3.9: `python -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025`) in a separate terminal to capture the message data.

† [aiosmtpd](https://aiosmtpd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) must be installed using `pip`. Unlike `smtpd` it is not part of the standard library.

Comment: `To`, `From` and `Subject` seems to be twice in the latter content. `em.set_content("{}".format(msg))` would fix the issue.

Comment: `"{}".format(value)` is just a really clumsy way to write `str(value)`, or simply `value` if the variable's value is already a string.

Comment: In the first example, you need an empty line after the `Subject:` line. But like you already note, the proper solution is to never assemble an email message from simple strings unless you know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: @tripleee Good spot! Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

For future readers, I had the same problem, I was trying to send an HTML email but I got the encoding error, I looked for several solutions but I couldn't find it, until I found that in the set_payload() method
You can add a second parameter, originally I had: `set_payload(email_content)`
then change it to `set_payload(email_content, charset='utf-8')`
and there I solved the error

```
self.msg['From'] = self.fromEmail
self.msg['To'] = toEmails
self.msg['Subject'] = subjectMsg

self.msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
self.msg.set_payload(email_content, charset='utf-8')

self.server.starttls()
    
self.server.login(self.msg['From'], self.password)

self.server.sendmail(self.msg['From'], self.msg['To'],
self.msg.as_string())
self.server.quit()

print("successfully sent email to %s:" % (self.msg['To']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the string into UTF-8 as shown below:

```
data = "dfgadshfgds"+\n+"dfdfb"

data = data.encode('utf-8')
```

then pass it to the server as a message!