# Cannot send email containing Cyrillic

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, smtplib

I'm super new to coding and as challenge I tried to scrape a website for weather data and then send that data to my email.
I suspect the Cyrillic is the reason email will fail to send.
I've run some tests and if I pass normal latin for my params 'subject' & 'msg'
the mail works, but if one of them has any non latin the mail will not go through. My knowledge with unicode is very limited and why that would even cause an error is unknown for me

```
import smtplib
import config
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def weather():
    src = requests.get('https://www.sinoptik.bg/asenovgrad-bulgaria-100733618').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

    city_name = soup.find('h1').text
    current_temp = soup.find('span', class_='wfCurrentTemp').text
    feels_temp = soup.find('span', class_='wfCurrentFeelTemp').text
    weather_type = soup.find('strong').text
    a = f'{city_name}\nТемпературата вмомента е {current_temp}\n{feels_temp}C\nОчаква се предимно {weather_type} време.'
    return a


def send_email(subject, msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(config.EMAIL_ADRESS, config.PASSWORD)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADRESS, config.SEND_TO, message)
        server.quit()
        print('Success: Email sent!')
    except:
        print('Email failed to send.')


subject = 'Дневна прогноза за времето'
msg = weather()

send_email(subject, msg)
```

when I remove try/except I get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-14: ordinal not in range(128)

using .encode('utf-8) I managed to get the email to send, but I receive ascii characters.

```
b'\xd0\x90\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\n\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb2\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xb5 18\xc2\xb0C\n\xd0\xa3\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd1\x89\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5: 18\xc2\xb0C\n\xd0\x9e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0 \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbf\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xa1\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8a\xd0\xbd\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5.'
```

then I tried decoding it back with .decode(), but email doesn't work again?

Comment: If you get any errors, please provide these in the question as a code block.
You most likely need to encode the string before passing it to the email function. You could do something along the lines of `send_email(subject.encode(), msg)`.

Comment: Well, the obvious solution would be to not use drunken letters in your email but if that's not an option you could try to google things like [unicode-emails-in-python](https://mg.pov.lt/blog/unicode-emails-in-python.html) -.-

Comment: you should get the error message from the server back in the smtp_error attribute of the server object

Comment: I wasn't getting any errors because i have the (Try: Except:)
when i removed it i get 
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 9-14: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The smtplib.server.sendmail function in python raises UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853197/the-smtplib-server-sendmail-function-in-python-raises-unicodeencodeerror-ascii)

Answer (score 0):

importing another module seems to partially solves the issue

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
```

then change the following:

```
message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADRESS, config.SEND_TO, message)
```

to

```
message = MIMEText('Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg))
server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADRESS, config.SEND_TO, message.as_string())
```

unfortunately this change affects the body of the email and the "Subject" no longer acts as one, but rather its inside the body of the email, leaving my "Subject" empty.

Comment: `MIMEText` is not a complete MIME message, just a MIME part. You want to start with a message and populate it.

Answer (score 0):

Email was originally strictly 7-bit ASCII, you have to use MIME encapsulation to properly include content of any other type and correctly add metadata to identify its type and encoding.  The `email` library does this for you transparently, and takes care of many other details which are hard or cumbersome to do by just smashing together strings (in particular if you are not very familiar with the requirements of RFC5322 and friends).

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject'] = 'Дневна прогноза за времето'
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
msg.set_content(weather())

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(config.EMAIL_ADRESS, config.PASSWORD)

server.send_message(msg)
server.quit()
```

This is pretty much the first example from https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html adapted to your circumstances.

Maybe notice that the `email` library was overhauled in Python 3.6; if you need to support an older version, some of the above might need minor tweaks.  It should not be hard to find examples once you know what to look for.