# Ascii codec can't encode character when sending email

Tags: python

I am sending email with python, but when sending I get this error msg:

[image]

Code:

```
if Quantidade <= Minimo:
   remetente    = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
   senha        = 'xxxxxxxxx'

   destinatario = ['xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx']
   assunto      = 'Stock Papelaria'
   texto        = 'O seguinte produto: {} encontra-se com a quantidade ({}) de stock igual ou inferior ao stock minimos.'.format(
        Produto, Quantidade)

   msg = '\r\n'.join([
      'From: %s' % remetente,
      'To: %s' % destinatario,
      'Subject: %s' % assunto,
      '',
      '%s' % texto
   ])

   server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
   server.starttls()
   server.login(remetente,senha)
   server.sendmail(remetente, destinatario, msg)
   server.quit()
```

The error I get is in the text line, where I have the product and quantity variables.
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Does `Produto` happen to be a string variable?

Comment: @Siddharth Srinivasan Yes, the problem is in the Product variable, because it has words like ã, for example

Comment: Could you try `Product.encode("utf-8")` and see if it works out?

Comment: @Siddharth Srinivasan After all resolved. Thank you

Comment: Did `utf-8` encoding work out?

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. This ASCII-only sample will never produce the claimed error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The smtplib.server.sendmail function in python raises UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853197/the-smtplib-server-sendmail-function-in-python-raises-unicodeencodeerror-ascii)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error generally occurs due to inconsistency between the string values being dealt with, mainly with mixing variables of type `str` with those of type `unicode`. Based on the [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type), we must encode it properly to `utf-8`. So `Produto` becomes `Produto.encode("utf-8")` instead.