# Discord.PY and SMPTlib 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 89-92: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, smtplib

( Discord.PY and SMTPlib )

Trying to make a Discord bot that sends emails via a "send" command. Everything working fine up until the actual command.

```
async def send(ctx, to):

    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send("What is the subject?")
    subject = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)
    await ctx.send("What is the body?")
    body = await bot.wait_for('message', check=check)

    subject = str(subject)
    body = str(body)

    smtpObj.sendmail('emailbotfordiscord@gmail.com', f'{to}', f'Subject: {subject}\n{body}')
```

Error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 89-92: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Is there any other way of doing this? Or how could I fix this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

( Please don't shut down my question if it doesn't have enough info I'll just edit it )

Comment: Odd... can't seem to track down the location of the error, do you mind adding a comment on which line the error seems to be occurring (maybe add the full traceback)

Comment: might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54853576/13042738

Comment: @Judev1 The code I sent is the only part where it seems to have an error. I think it has to do with not being able to use variables for emails