# UnicodeEncodeError at / 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, django-views, encode

This error occurs when django tries to use the send_email function:

```
UnicodeEncodeError at /
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8002/
Django Version: 4.2.2
Exception Type: UnicodeEncodeError
Exception Value:    
'ascii' codec can't encode character '\x92' in position 65: ordinal not in range(128)
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.11/smtplib.py, line 641, in auth
```

in views.py:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail EmailMessage
def contactView(request):
    email = EmailMessage(
            'encoded_subject',
            'Body',
            'obidjonova07@mail.ru',
            ['inspiring.sunset07@gmail.com'],
        )
        email.send()
    return render(request, "parts/base.html", {'birth_date': age})
```

I tried using encode function:

```
encoded_subject = subject.encode('utf-8')
```

and passed it to the function, tried to use the function for the message as well, but it did not help

Comment: Does this thread help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54853197/the-smtplib-server-sendmail-function-in-python-raises-unicodeencodeerror-ascii